# How to override the enabled /disabled look on a button in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm assuming that this may be a style issue, but being new to wpf I'm not sure what I should be changing.  I have built a user control containg various buttons (whose background colour I have set to be transparent).  None the less when added to a form or other user control they exhibit a coloured background when disabled, or when run over by the mouse when enabled (see illustration below)

[image]

What do I need to do to remove the grey background on the button's disabled state, and also the blue background that appears on rollover when it is enabled.  My aim is to try aand retain a clean and clear rendition of the button images.

Thanks

Comment: Currently I use the IsEnabledChanged event of the buttons to swap out the displayed images, so if they see a greyed version of the button's image it's disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to override the `ControlTemplate` of the `Button` controls using a `Style.` The following `Style` will apply to all `Button` controls, but you can specify a `Key` for the `Style` and use it on specific `Button` controls if you wish.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonContent">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonContent"
                                    Property="Background"
                                    Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```